# Проблемы с кириллицей в Rust

Tags: rust

При попытке вывести пресловутый "Привет мир" через println! компилятор выдаёт ошибку "stream did not  contain valid UTF-8" и отказывается это добро компилировать.
Проект пустой, созданный с помощью cargo new, если заменить кириллицу на латиницу - исправно выводит.
У меня было подозрение, что он в принципе не дружит с русским языком, но первый же пример из книги "Язык программирования Rust" является этим самым "привет миром", который там же спокойно компилируется кнопочкой ► на странице с книгой.

Версия Rust - 1.44.0
Проект чистый и созданный только что.
В интернете решения проблемы найдено мной не было.
В остальном компилятор работает исправно, контейнеры с crates.io подтягивает, ни с чем другим не конфликтует.
Редактировал через Visual Studio и Notepad++, эффект одинаковый

Comment: В Notepad++ при сохранении есть выбор кодировки, вот и выберите там UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо товарищу andreymal!
Нужно было просто сменить в Notepad++ кодировку на UTF-8.
Надеюсь, существование этого вопроса здесь поможет кому-то не очень разумному вроде меня.